# Apache Tika - not indexing email attachments

Tags: apache, email, attachment, jackrabbit, apache-tika

I am using Apache Jackrabbit 2.6.0 as my document management system.

When I upload email type of document with attachment, it index the email content properly. However, it doesn't index content of attachment.

I went through source code of Jackrabbit & while debugging observed that it uses Apache Tika to extract text from binary files like office documents (msg, docx etc...). It seems, OutlookExtractor.java is unable to identify correct parser for attachment type of document.

I am using default config in tika-config.xml (it's used by repository.xml of jackrabbit).

Please let me know in case of any tips or direction from anyone. Am I missing anything specific to email & attachment in tika-config ?

Comment: What kind of attachment is it?

Comment: Its simple email with attachment of MsWord document (doc & docx).

Comment: Does the [Tika App](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) manage to extract out the attachments? eg with `java -jar tika-app-1.3.jar -z`? That'll tell you if it's a Tika issue, or a Jackrabbit integration one

Comment: Yes it shows what all attachments are in an email msg file. But how to make sure its extracting content of attachment?

Comment: In between, I made few changes in Tika core & parser. Now Its indexing the attachment but I am not sure if that is the best way forward. If required, I can provide you for your review.

Comment: Just observed one issue with that, these changes in tika core & parser dont extract content from attached word document (.doc).

Comment: You shouldn't need to be making any changes to Tika itself. Your problem is with how Jackrabbit is calling Tika, any changes are needed in that code to ensure that Jackrabbit requests Tika recurse into embedded resources

Comment: Completely Agree with you. But Jackrabbit provides configuration to use tika via tika-config.xml. From tika source code debug, I have confirmed that at last tika calls DelegatingParser.java for attached resources but everytime it returns EmptyParser instance. Do you think, any additional configuration is required to parse/recurse embedded resources into email?

Comment: Playing with TikaConfig won't help - you need to specify a recursing parser on the `ParseContext` if you want embedded resources

Comment: Yes that's what I would like to know. Where can we specify recurring parser for the ParseContext. (in configuration or in code)

Comment: No idea, you'll need to find someone who knows JackRabbit... What you'll need to do is something like `parseContext.set(Parser.class, new AutoDetectParser());`

Comment: That's what I have done to fix email with attachment extraction in Tika. Jackrabbit passes document & it's mime type to tika. Tika decides the parsing context. So currently, I have made this change in Tika's OutlookExtractor.java file. It's working fine for email with attachment. However, I will discuss this issue in Jackrabbit forum as well.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your valuable time & comments. Your suggestions helped me a lot. :)